# LISTAGG Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g, listagg

I am using LISTAGG to concatenate my string, here one problem I am facing - while concatenating it is throwing the below error

"result of string concatenation is too long.
 String concatenation result is more than the maximum size.
 Make sure that the result is less than the maximum size. "

I want the concatenated string to be more than 4000 characters...

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result to be more than 4000 characters and you are using 11g, you cannot use `listagg`.  `listagg` returns a `varchar2` and a `varchar2` in SQL is limited to 4000 bytes (that can be increased to 32k in 12.1 and my guess is that `listagg` would then be able to return a string up to 32k in length but I haven't tried that).

In 11g, if you want the result to be longer than 4000 bytes, you'd have to use a `clob`.  The best way I know of to do that is to take the [user-defined aggregate function](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques#user_defined_aggregate_function) from Tim Hall's page on Oracle string aggregation techniques and modify it to use and return `clob` rather than `varchar2`.  One example of a CLOB-based implementation is available on [this German language site](http://sql-plsql-de.blogspot.com.au/2014/01/sql-listagg-mit-clob-ausgabe-kein.html) though the code is easy enough to read even if you aren't a German speaker.